# Argument of type Pinia is not assignable to parameter of type Plugin<[]>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

I'm using Pinia with Vue3 and Vuetify in typescript. When I'm performing a build with vite, I've got this error.

```
Argument of type Pinia is not assignable to parameter of type Plugin<[]>
```

I'm initializing Pinia following the official documentation :

```
import vuetify from './vuetify';
import router from '../router';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import type { Pinia } from 'pinia';

// Types
import type { App } from 'vue';

export function registerPlugins(app: App) {
  const pinia: Pinia = createPinia();
  app.use(vuetify).use(router).use(pinia);
}
```

I've got the same error with juste `app.use(pinia)`

Edit: here are my versions :

```
"pinia": "^2.1.7",
"vue": "^3.4.10",
"vue-router": "^4.2.5",
"vuetify": "^3.4.0",
"typescript": "~5.2.0",
"vite": "4.4.6",
"vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.2"
```

It fails also with type check : `vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json --composite false`

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": [
    "env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/__tests__/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "out",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, which versions of vue and vite are you using ? Also, are you using Pinia on server-side (I guess yes since this corresponds to the SSR doc) ?

Comment: I'm installing pinia like the Getting started doc says.
https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html.
I'm using pinia 2.1.7, vite 4.4.6, vue 3.4.10. It fails also without vite, just with "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.json --composite false"

Comment: I don't get this error. I started from the Stackblitz provided by Pinia and added your code and versions and I don't get the error : https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-th9n6s?file=src%2Fmain.ts . Maybe something is different with your tsconfig.json